# Editing CSS without module/plugin

Tags: blocks

I am working on a website developed by a previous developer so I am studying how I can edit the style without source code or any extension... is there any possibility to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible; Drupal doesn't have an interface for editing CSS out of the box.

You'll either need to get into the code, or install/develop a module like [CSS Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_editor).